# Is it grammatically correct to say “Utilities Operations”?

Tags: grammatical-number

My department is titled *Utilities Operations.*  We run the utilities (heating, cooling, power) for a public university.

It seems to me that the correct title should be either *Utility Operations* or *Utilities Operation.*

Comment: It appears to be a pronoun, therefore you can call it whatever you want.  However, "Utility Operations" is the most idiomatic I think.

Comment: @MaxWilliams: Did you mean *proper noun?*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft "pronoun" is a shortened version of "proper noun".

Comment: @MaxWilliams: Nope, *[pronoun](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pronoun)* is a semi-anglification of the Latin *pronomen,* which is composed of *pro* (instead of) and *nomen* (name). Pronouns are a word class (containing such words as *we, it, they*) that is entirely distinct from proper names.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I stand corrected, and beg your pardon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [singular/ plural in the attributive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160506/singular-plural-in-the-attributive). Also see ['Woman' or 'women' as a stand-in for the adjective 'female'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161590/woman-or-women-as-a-stand-in-‌​for-the-adjective-female/161619#161619).

Comment: A department title can be pretty much anything.  And which one would be preferred would depend on the details of the department's responsibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already hinted in the comments and by the capitalization of the two words, **Utilities Operations** is a proper noun. At least the person who named it thought so. As a proper noun grammaticality does not really apply.

As Max Williams already provided, Utility Operations is the most used of all combinations of pluralization as evident in this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=utility+operations%2C+utilities+operations%2C+utility+operation%2C+utilities+operation&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cutility%20operations%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Butility%20operations%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUtility%20Operations%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUTILITY%20OPERATIONS%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUtility%20operations%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cutilities%20operations%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Butilities%20operations%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUtilities%20Operations%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cutility%20operation%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Butility%20operation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUtility%20Operation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUtility%20operation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cutilities%20operation%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BUtilities%20Operation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Butilities%20operation%3B%2Cc0).

Since you however ask specifically for the grammaticality of the term that does not help you. Besides the arbitary spelling possibilites of a proper noun the combination is more or less a compound noun (I cannot name an English compound noun with both parts in plural right now). Most of them are pluralized at the last word ([Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/grammatik/britisch-grammatik/nouns-compound-nouns)).

So, if you want to use the two words in a sentence without referring to your department the best possibility might be **utility operations**.

Answer (score 0):

I believe *Utilities Operations* is correct since they're two separate nouns unlike if it were used as a compound noun in which case it would be *Utility-Operations*

Think of it this way; how would the words *Utility Operations* indicate that the department dealt with multiple *operation*s for **more than one *Utility*.**

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the point that the department name is a "proper name" and thus exempt from the rules, "utility department" would be most appropriate if one group within the department directly provided service for all the different utilities, whereas "utilities department" would be more appropriate if the department contained separate internal groups for the individual classes of utilities, or if the department simply contracted out to the various external utility/maintenance companies.